# Amcharts shows data only on resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a really strange error while  using AmCharts preview in twitter bootstrap modal.
Actually its  a modal that is used to preview some graph data but it does not actually shows graphs  sometimes until:

-I open inspect element dialog.(means window resize event)
-Or by re sizing the inspect element dialog if its already open.(again means window resize event)
-I manually resize browser window

From perspective of my backend there is no problem sending data it always send same data.

I know my problem is really silly but i think may be someone might occurred with this one.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try giving inline width & height to dialog.

Comment: Just making sure, but you're not using chrome dev release are you?

Comment: @RussellKompinski no i using normal user chrome release.

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem, fixed by resizing after modal is shown

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
chart.invalidateNow();
chart.validateSize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem too, so try this one its works for me:

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
           chart.validateData();
           chart.animateAgain();
 });
```

Actually you can just add `chart.animateAgain();` on your `shown.bs.modal` to redraw the chart.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions didn't work for me.  For me, this did the trick:

```
chart.invalidateSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, and below code worked for me.

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
}, 500);
```